# How to keep separate log configuration files, one for each environment, and have build automated by maven

Tags: logging, maven

Through Maven I can build a project with the logging configuration file.

Wonder if it possible to keep a configuration descriptor, one per environment (performance, production, sit, uat, developer) and have the build automated by maven.

Not sure if the correct way is to have multiple pom.xml, one for each environment, and then calling the desired pom.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at having [multiple profiles](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Build+Profiles) - one for each environment.  In each profile, you can specify the appropriate descriptor.  You would need to run a maven build for each profile and get the appropriate artifact.

Answer (score 2):

I have described the problem you have in my blog posts [here](http://blog.soebes.de/index.php?/archives/340-Maven-Configuration-For-Multipe-Environments.html) and [here](http://blog.soebes.de/index.php?/archives/341-Maven-Configuration-For-Multipe-Environments-II.html) and how to solve that problem with Maven.

Answer (score 1):

Separate POMs are definitely a no-no. Whenever you have a configuration change irrelevant to your logging problem, you'll have to remember to update all your pom variants.

Profiles mentioned above are one option; another could be [Maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I will look into the option you provided.